# how to make this road not scale itself.And make equally big portion(like size big) sections of the road

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Im currently trying to make a road movement animation but cant figure how the road must not scale itself.
The whole code isn`t mine it is from a tutorial ,I just tried to modify it to my needs ,but I cant do the part that the road should move like if Im seeing it from above(bird view) ,at always same speed.
currently i have this swf file

http://www.stouchgames.com/APKs/Road.swf

I dont want it to be like little lines in the top and then in the bottom a big line that moves.I just want to be equally Big lines that move from top to bottom.
So far i have a simple movieClip with 2 frames and the frames have the graphics in this picture:

http://stouchgames.com/APKs/road.jpg

and this code :

```
package {

      import flash.display.MovieClip;
      import flash.events.Event;

      public class Main extends MovieClip {

                //Depth of the visible road
                private const roadLines:int = 320;
                //Dimensions of the play area.
                private const resX:int = 480;
                private const resY:int = 320;
                //Line of the player's car.
                private const noScaleLine:int = 8;
                //All the road lines will be accessed from an Array.
                private var yMap:Array = [];
                private var lines:Array = [];
                private var halfWidth:Number;
                private var lineDepth:int;
                private const widthStep:Number = 0;

                private var playerY:Number;

                private var speed:int = 2;
                private var texOffset:int = 100;


                public function Main() {
                          //Populate the zMap with the depth of the road lines
                          for (var i:int = 0; i < roadLines; i++) {
                                    yMap.push(1 / (i - resY));
                          }

                          playerY = 100 / yMap[noScaleLine];


                          for (i = 0; i < roadLines; i++) {
                                    yMap[i] *=  playerY;
                          }
                          //Make the line at the bottom to be in front of the rest,
                          //and add every line at the same position, bottom first.
                          lineDepth = numChildren;
                          for (i = 0; i < roadLines; i++) {
                                    var line = new Road();
                                    lines.push(line);
                                    addChildAt(line, lineDepth);
                                    line.x = resX / 2;
                                    line.y = resY - i;
                          }
                          //Scaling the road lines according to their position

                         addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, race);
                }

                private function race(event:Event):void {
                          for (var i:int = 0; i < roadLines; i++) {
                                    if ((yMap[i] + texOffset) % 100 > 50) {
                                              lines[i].gotoAndStop(1);
                                    } else {
                                              lines[i].gotoAndStop(2);
                                    }
                          }
                          texOffset = texOffset + speed;
                          while (texOffset >= 100) {
                                    texOffset -=  100;
                          }
                }
      }
```

}

i did try to just make just 2 road movieClips with the different graphics ,then use a

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            if (((i % 2) == 0)) {
                var line = new Road  ;
                lines.push(line);
                addChildAt(line,lineDepth);
                line.x = resX / 2;
                line.y = resY - i * 50;
                line.alpha = .2;
            }
            if (((i % 2) == 1)) {
                var line = new Road2  ;
                lines.push(line);
                addChildAt(line,lineDepth);
                line.x = resX / 2;
                line.y = resY - i * 50;
                line.alpha = .5;
            }
```

but then when i get in the Event.EVERY frame function i cant make them move smoothly ... and decided it must be done by the 1st way cause of the much more detailed ending and cause in the end if i want to change the resolutions of the road i can do it much easier with it . Ofcourse i could be wrong cause i haven`t done such a thing  like this before.

So can someone help ?

Comment: the fla file is in this link if anyone needs it

http://www.stouchgames.com/APKs/Road.fla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace ***yMap[i]*** with ***i*** in race function:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < roadLines; i++) {
    if ((i + texOffset) % 100 > 50) {
         lines[i].gotoAndStop(1);
    } else {
         lines[i].gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```